# logging into site via API

Tags: api, theory

We are allowing developers to have their users log into our site/platform via API.  The login will hit our API thru HTTPS so it will at least pass the username and password over securely.

But after that, what is the most efficient way to "log" this person in via API?  This is what I am thinking.

// app passes username and password to API

// our API processes the username and password.

// if login fails, output failure code

// if login is successful, then create an authcode and save it within the user's table.  send the authcode and user_id back to the app

Now, each time the user performs an action (such as makes a comment) and it hits our API, we require the user_id and authcode in order to authenticate.

Am I missing anything?  Should I include an expire column to "log out" the user after X hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your process is fine. It's the same way some major API's on the internet work.

There are some things you can consider adding (now or in the future):

- *created-on* (for the log out function). I would advise to expire them after a specific period (even if it's like a month)
- *miss*, that counts every time the user_id is hit in the API with a 'non-authenticated' authcode. This way you can detect brute forcing and decide if you want to add other countermeasures as well (such as locking the authcode to an IP).
- *ip*, to lock the authcode to an IP to prevent brute forcing